# How can I visualize this Compound Interest Chart with indefinite integrals?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, visualization

How can I visualize [the integrals below](https://betterexplained.com/articles/definitions-of-e-colorized/)? Can someone draw on the chart and point to where $\int 1 \, dx = x$, $\int x \, dx = \frac 12 x^2 $, ... are ? I don't know [which of these charts](https://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-simple-compound-and-continuous-interest-rates/) are more intuitive, and I'll copy and paste two. Is this called a Bar Chart?

[image]

> From a calculus perpsective, here's what's happening:
>
> - Our initial quantity is 1 (for all time)
> - This principal earns 100% continuous interest, and after time x
>   has earned $\int 1 \, dx = x$. (After 1 unit of time, this is 1)
> - After time x, that interest (x) has earned $\int x \, dx = \frac 12 x^2 $. (After 1 unit of time, this is $\frac 12$)
> - After time x, that interest ($\frac 12 x^2$) has earned $\int \frac 12 x^2 \, dx = \frac 1{3!} x^3 $ (After 1 unit of time, this is \frac 1{3!} = \frac 16)
>
> And so on. Every instant, the entire chain of interest is growing. When learning calculus, you might have repeatedly tried to integrate x just for fun (whatever gets you going). That game is how we end up with e.

[image]

Comment: A little correction. Indefinite integrals are not related to any kind of area and can't be visualized that way. In this case we really need to define the limits for each integral. In any case, these diagrams seem confusing to me, rather than helpful

Comment: to express compound interest you use the exponential function and curiously the Taylor series around zero is $$e^{x} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^7}{7!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} + \cdots$$

Comment: @YuriyS You're correct! Thanks. Please do draw on that picture as you see fit.

Comment: We can easily visualize $\int_0^x \tfrac {t^n}{n!} dt$ for each fixed $n$, for instance, [for $n=2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0zXM.png), but I do not see a natural visualization of a recursive sequence of integrals 
$$1, \int_0^x 1 dt =\frac {x}{1!},  \int_0^x \frac {t}{1!} dt =\frac {x^2}{2!}, \int_0^x \frac {t^2}{2!} dt= \frac {x^3}{3!},\dots .$$